# Spring Cloud Stream configuration options

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Hi All I am a complete newbie to the Spring Cloud Streams framework.

In the spring cloud stream docs for Kafka Streams,I can see that properties with the prefix spring.cloud.stream.function.definition etc. are referenced in the application yaml/properties file used in the examples.

My question is : Where can I find a complete reference to all properties available to be set in the application.yaml for Spring cloud stream applications for Kafka streams ?

I understand that Cloud streams uses Cloud Function, but then the cloud streams configuration has an additional "stream" group/block within the properties, so I am not sure how I can get access to a complete template yaml which lists all available properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for general Spring Cloud Stream aspects and specific Kafka binder subjects contains information about which configuration properties are available.

- [Spring Cloud Stream general configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_configuration_options)
- [Kafka binder configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_configuration_options)
- [Kafka Stream binder configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_configuration_options_2)

You can also check the Java classes storing all the configuration data for a comprehensive list of properties:

- org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceProperties
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderProperties
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ConsumerProperties
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ProducerProperties

The Kafka and Kafka Streams bindings extend the base properties with extra ones, that you can find in the following packages:

- org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.properties
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.properties